# BotComposer - QnA management should always be routed through Composer?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

BotComposer offers a single touchpoint to maintain LUIS, QnA and Bot Authoring.
However, for making any changes in QnA model (QnA pair CRUD operations), do we always have to follow Composer authoring and deployment path?

Reason I am asking is, if some one directly makes changes in QnA pairs through portal, it would make the LUIS inconsistent, if it has been cross trained via CrossTrainedRecognizerSet in Composer Dialog.

Am I missing anything? How the management cycle should look like for QnA maintainence, if Bot has been deployed through Composer.

Answer (score 1):

> do we always have to follow Composer authoring and deployment path?

Yes, unfortunately. At least at this point. I believe work is being done to make this less cumbersome.

> Am I missing anything? How the management cycle should look like for QnA maintainence, if Bot has been deployed through Composer.

You should make your changes to QnA from Composer and then re-publish.